# Why am I just taking the picture url from the last url?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtnetwork

I wrote a program to extract link pictures from webcomics, however, when I run it, it just extracts image links from the last link chapter, not all image links from all chapters. What is the issue with my program?
I have tried several ways but not things useful.

```
from PyQt5 import QtNetwork, QtCore
from requests_html import HTML
from functools import cached_property
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QUrl

url1 = "https://saytruyen.net/truyen-su-tro-lai-cua-phap-su-hac-am-sau-66666-nam.html"

class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.handle_response)

    @cached_property
    def manager(self):
        return QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()

    def start(self):
        self.start_request(QtCore.QUrl(url1))

    def start_request(self, url):
        request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
        self.manager.get(request)

    def handle_response(self, reply):
        err = reply.error()
        if err == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
            self.process(str(reply.readAll(), 'utf-8'))
        else:
            print("Error occured: ", err)
            print(reply.errorString())

    def process(self, data):
        html = HTML(html=data)
        rs = html.find("#list-chapter a", first=False)
        for i in reversed(rs):
            url2 = "https://saytruyen.net/" + i.attrs["href"]
            #print(url2)
            #self.start_request(QtCore.QUrl(url2))
            req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url2))

            self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
            self.nam.finished.connect(self.handleResponse)
            self.nam.get(req)

    def handleResponse(self, reply):

        er = reply.error()

        if er == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:

            bytes_string = reply.readAll()
            html2 = HTML(html = str(bytes_string, 'utf-8'))
            rs_c = html2.find("#lst_content img")
            for x in rs_c:
                img ="https://saytruyen.net/" + x.attrs['src']
                print(img)

        else:
            print("Error occured: ", er)
            print(reply.errorString())
        
        QCoreApplication.quit()
```

Comment: Try moving the first two lines of `self.nam` in the `__init__`.

Comment: This way is not effective

Comment: It should: the problem is that you're constantly recreating a new QNetworkAccessManager in the for loop, so the result is that the previous one gets garbage collected (deleted) and only the last created one is able to "survive" and process the request. Only one manager for the new urls should exist, and only `self.nam.get(req)` should exist in the for loop. Also, you shouldn't obviously quit at the end of `handleResponse`, otherwise the other requests will never be processed.

Comment: oh thank it working

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. the QNetworkAccessManager used for the download is being continuously recreated; since a network request is asynchronous, it isn't processed instantly, and it will be destroyed along with the network manager in the next cycle of the for loop since it's being overwritten; the result is that the previous request will be destroyed and only the last one will "survive";
2. the application is quit as soon as the *first* reply is received, preventing all other requests to be processed;

The solution is to create a *single* manager for the download process in the `__init__`, and quit as soon as all requests have been received.

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.handle_response)
        self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.handleResponse)
        self.urls = set()

    # ...

    def process(self, data):
        html = HTML(html=data)
        rs = html.find("#list-chapter a", first=False)
        for i in reversed(rs):
            url2 = QUrl("https://saytruyen.net/" + i.attrs["href"])
            if url2 in self.urls:
                continue
            self.urls.add(url2)
            req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url2)
            self.nam.get(req)

    def handleResponse(self, reply):
        self.urls.discard(reply.url())
        er = reply.error()

        if er == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
            bytes_string = reply.readAll()
            html2 = HTML(html = str(bytes_string, 'utf-8'))
            rs_c = html2.find("#lst_content img")
            for x in rs_c:
                img ="https://saytruyen.net/" + x.attrs['src']
                print(img)

        else:
            print("Error occured: ", er)
            print(reply.errorString())

        if not self.urls:
            QCoreApplication.quit()
```

Note that it's usually enough (and better) to have a *single* network manager and properly handle responses based on queued requests, but for simple situations like this one having two managers doesn't represent a huge problem.

Comment: Can you show me full code with my link above and if __name__ == __"main"__

Comment: No, the provided code is sufficient. You should not just copy and paste solutions, you should read and study them so that you can understand what they do.

Comment: I don’t mean i just only copy code because when i run that line have a problem: self.urls.add(url2)

Comment: Then just tell that you have a problem, and clarify *what* "problem" that is.

Comment: when running it gave me an error message that it didn't have an add variable when I changed set() to input but left set() and added Link almost the code didn't work because set() separates the whole thing  Link out

Comment: Sorry but your comment is very confused. If you have problems writing in English, please look for somebody that can help you, and if you get an error, don't try to explain what it says: copy and paste it! What do you mean by "I changed set() to input"? What does the rest of the comment mean?